# divorce contract vs tax law

Tags: united-states, contract-law, divorce, tax-law

My (PA) divorce contract states that a benefit (child or education credit) one of us receives from claiming a dependent will be shared.  Under the tax law, my ex does not qualify to receive the credit since he makes too much  money.  does the contract stating we'll share supersede the tax law & am I obligated to share?

Comment: You can't both claim as a dependent, right?  So depending on who claims the state gives the credit or not?

Comment: I am the custodial parent so ex cannot claim unless I sign form 8832.  Even if ex claims dependent he won't get the credit.  I'm trying to find out if the court can award money the IRS says isn't his